# AWS Cloud formation - create EC2 instance with security group name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I am trying to create a cloud formation template to create EC2 instance. I would like to use Security Group Name instead of  Security Group Id. When I use that I am getting error "Encountered unsupported property SecurityGroup". How can I use Security Group Name while creating EC2 Instance through Cloud Formation

```
"Resources": 
{
    "EC2Instance":
    {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties":
        {
            "InstanceType": 
            {
                "Ref": "InstanceType"
            },
            "SecurityGroup":
            [
                {
                    "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup"
                }
            ],
            "KeyName":
            {
                "Ref" : "AWS::Region"
            },
            "ImageId":
            {
                "Ref": "AMI"
            }
        }
    },
    "InstanceSecurityGroup":
    {
        "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": 
        {
            "GroupDescription": "Enable SSH access via port 22",
            "GroupName": 
            {
                "Fn::FindInMap":
                [
                    "EnvironmentConfig",
                    {
                        "Ref": "Environment"
                    },
                    "SGGroupName"
                ]
            },
            "SecurityGroupIngress":
            [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "CidrIp":"10.252.0.0/16"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "CidrIp":"10.251.0.0/16"
                }           
            ],
            "VpcId": 
            {
                "Fn::FindInMap":
                [
                    "EnvironmentConfig",
                    {
                        "Ref":"Environment"
                    },
                    "VPC"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be SecurityGroups instead of SecurityGroup, i.e.

```
"SecurityGroups" : [{ "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" }]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html